# IntelliJ - Code completion finds import but compiler doesn't?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a certain module (A) in my Java project that uses classes from another module (B).

Module B is added to module A's dependencies.

It seems that a few classes, which originate from Module B, cannot be resolved in module A on compiling the module.

The compiler marks the import of the classes and says that the class to be imported does not exist there.
*However*, when i manually type the exact same import, IntelliJ's code completion suggests exactly what i have written as import - so the code completion knows of the class and finds it.
As well as the code inspection also doesn't complain. The line isn't marked red or anything.

Only on compile IntelliJ seems to be unable to find the import - all of sudden.

Invalidating caches and restarting has yielded no result.

**Does anyone have an idea what might cause this or has even experienced it?**

Comment: A bug might cause it.

Comment: IntelliJ compiles classes automatically after you have modified them. These compiled classes are kept inside of IntelliJ's environment (cached or some other directory). If you have a maven dependency management in place, you need to install module b first and afterwards you should be able to install or compile module a - maybe an update of module a may be necessary, depending on your settings. You can also change your maven structure to utilize [multi-module maven project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: If you don't have maven (gradle, ...) dependency-management in place but use the IntelliJ modules [similar to this setup](http://postimg.org/image/i1ae4vsmx/), you should be able to compile the whole project on right clicking the project (NoDependencyManagment in the picture) and selecting `Compile NoDependencyManagment` - this should compile ModuleB before ModuleA

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, Roman. I don't quite know why it was this way, but i actually also build the project using an ant build file. It writes to the same folders that IntelliJ is configured with so that these two can work with each other.
I guess for some reason IntelliJ's indexing was messed or i dont know. I had to recompile using the ant build and then let IntelliJ reindex. 

It's a little magic and intransparent to me why it is that way, the whole things setup is a little complex.
You mentioning maven made me remember that i might want to rerun the ant build and see. Thanks!